# Conflicting getters for com.google.type.Money - Java

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, types

I am building an application to run with Firestore and I am facing a trouble with money.

Since Firebase does not support BigDecimal, I am trying to use the Money class. But there is a error being displayed `java.lang.RuntimeException: Found conflicting getters for name getDefaultInstanceForType on class com.google.type.Money`.

I have accessed the Decompiled file of the Money class and really there is two getters:
[image]

[In the decumentation](http://googleapis.github.io/googleapis/java/all/latest/apidocs/com/google/type/Money.html) of this class there is only one method, so I dont know how to proceed.

Here is the problem in Money class decompiled from my IntelliJ IDEA:

```java
//
// Source code recreated from a .class file by IntelliJ IDEA
// (powered by FernFlower decompiler)
//

package com.google.type;

.... HIDDEN FIELDS ....

public final class Money extends GeneratedMessageV3 implements MoneyOrBuilder {


 .... HIDDEN FIELDS BY ME ....

    public Money getDefaultInstanceForType() {
        return DEFAULT_INSTANCE;
    }

.... MORE HIDDEN FIELDS ....

        public Money getDefaultInstanceForType() {
            return Money.getDefaultInstance();
        }
       
      
.... AND MORE HIDDEN FIELDS ...

    }
}
```

If you would like to see the entire class, [here is a link to a notion page](https://actually-kookaburra-4e5.notion.site/Google-Money-Class-60f61047a00d4759a2d573289feb66ef)

What should I do?

Oh, and here's my model (by privacy clauses, I'm hiding some parts):

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Document(collectionName = "ModelClassCollection")
public class MyModelClass {

    @DocumentId
    private String id;

 .... HIDDEN FIELDS  ....

    private Money total;

    private Money municipalTax;

    private Money federalTax;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the content of your `Money` class. Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: @AlexMamo hello, I have applied the changes. Can you check it out?

Comment: There is too much going on there. You should isolate the problem.

Comment: @AlexMamo allright, I have isolate it. Can you check it out?

Comment: How does your database look like?

Comment: @AlexMamo there is no database running, the application is on build step. The model of Firestore is the one that I have displayed on the question.

Answer (score 0):

The mere problem is that you're not going to add annotations into `class Money` and you're also not going to extend `final class Money`. This means, you can't just take some random class, that sounds alike and then expect it to be cast-able. There are no type-converters for Firestore, but one still can override [`DocumentSnapshot.toObject()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#public-t-toobject-classt-valuetype)... and monetary values generally can safely be stored eg. as `Integer` cents, to be converted to `BigDecimal` on demand.

Comment: Martin, I don't understand. I am not trying to override Money class. You're trying to say that Money class cannot be used to work with money?

Here we're trying to not store money in cents, but if nothing work as well we will gonna use it. 

My question is why there is two methods with same signature in Money class? And if Money class is not recommended to store Money, why does it exists?